# How do I make a table's columns fill the width not occupied by fixed-width columns?

Tags: html, css

I have a 5-column table whose first and last columns have fixed (and different) widths. How do I force the 3 center columns to be equally distributed across the remaining width of the table?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="first">A<td>
        <td id="second">B<td>
        <td id="third">C<td>
        <td id="fourth">D<td>
        <td id="fifth">E<td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table { width: 100%; }
td#first { width: 100px; }
td#fifth { width: 200px; }
```

When the browser is 1200px wide, I want #second, #third, and #fourth to be ( 1200 - ( 100 + 200 ) ) / 3 = 300px wide. Ideally I would not be making changes to the HTML's structure.

Thanks!

Edit: Ideally this would work regardless of the number of non-fixed-width columns.

**Answer**:

Thanks to user Chris below for his answer. This is the minimum CSS (minus the border) that makes it work: http://plnkr.co/edit/3K5hE0Kn5D9S7bIDbOPl?p=preview

Comment: What is the required browser support? Also, what is it currently doing?

Comment: No specific backwards-compatibility requirements; modern versions of the most common browsers. Currently the middle columns' widths are affected by their contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about trying the following?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      table{width: 100%; font-size: 0; line-height: 12px; table-layout: fixed;}
      td {border: 1px solid black; }
      #first{ min-width: 10px; width: 10px; }
      #second{ min-width: 20px; width: 20px; }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <td id="first">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="second">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="third">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="fourth">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="fifth">&nbsp;</td>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SRo9hcIVxFznFbbzA2fq?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, when I make the table 100% width, the 'fixed-width' columns do not maintain fixed widths: http://plnkr.co/edit/pSrMwQZmVL0RKUSugIU5?p=preview

Comment: /slow-claps
#tableguru

Comment: Thanks!! Can you explain what (if anything) the "width: 20%" is doing in the td style (since we are re-writing the width of the fixed columns)?

Comment: I stripped it down and will update my post with the minimum CSS. Thanks again!

Comment: In hindsight I think you're better off without that width on td. When I change the line-height to 10 to match the intended width of the first column, it does not come to a perfect square. When I remove the width: 20% on the td tags it fixes that problem.